# How to use `headerFilter` with `editor:autolookup`?

Tags: tabulator

I have table. One field is generic, but another is lookup.
I use some list to display readable values instead of raw numbers.

I try to write custom `headerFilter` for such column, but it is not called at all.

Try to filter data in `ID` column and `Country` column at next [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KES777/hc729L8v/7/) code:

```
var header_filter = function( headerValue, rowValue, rowData, filterParams ) {
  alert( 'Called' );
  headerValue =  headerValue.replace( / /g, '.*' );
  var re =  new RegExp( headerValue, 'i' );

  return rowValue.search( re ) >= 0;
}


//Build Tabulator
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    data: tabledata,
    columns:[
        {title:"ID", field:"id", width:40, headerFilter: true, headerFilterFunc: header_filter, },
        {title:"Country", field:"country_id", width:130, editor:"autocomplete", editorParams:{values: country_list, showListOnEmpty: true, }, formatter: "lookup", formatterParams: country_list,
        headerFilter: true, headerFilterFunc: header_filter,        
        },
    ],
});
```

What did I wrong? How to use custom header filter on lookup field?

Answer (score 0):

You can not. This is prohibited:

Look at [source](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/master/src/js/modules/filter.js#L237)

```
if(!(column.definition.headerFilter === "autocomplete" 
    || (column.definition.editor === "autocomplete" 
        && column.definition.headerFilter === true))){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use am autocomplete in the header filter to filter data, you just cant live filter data (ie the filter changes as you type in the autocomplete) it is only filtered when a value is selected from the autocomplete list

Comment: autoselect list does not appear. I can not select anything. [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KES777/woxeqka2/)

Comment: In your example you don't have any headerFilterParams set so it has no idea how to configure the autocomplete

Comment: I have updated [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KES777/woxeqka2/). `headerFilterParams` has now effect =(